# different speed of three sphere

Tags: processing

I am a new coder on processing, that's why please be gentle.I made a simple code for you. Normally my code is more longer and complex.However, I wrote a simple code for you.

```
//main class
ArrayList<Clouds> clouds = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
  size(1200, 800, P3D);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    Clouds C = new Clouds();
    clouds.add(C);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0); 
  for (int i = 0; i < clouds.size(); i++)
  {
    clouds.get(i).drawClouds();
  }
}

//Clouds class

class Clouds
{
  float xC, yC, zC, speedC;
  public Clouds()
  {
    xC = 20;
    yC = 40;
    zC = 0;
    noStroke();
    speedC = 1;
  }
  public void drawClouds()
  {
    translate(xC,yC);
    pushMatrix();
    makingClouds(100, 100, 100);
    popMatrix();
    if (xC > width - 780) {
      xC = -660; 
    }
    xC += speedC; 
  }
  public void makingClouds(float xF, float yF, float zF ) {
    translate(xF, yF, zF);
    pushMatrix();
    lights();
    scale(1, 1, 1);
    sphere(20);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

I hope, I'm not doing wrong with writing two class in here but I've worked on it two whole days and made me sick. So my question is: Like you see, there are three sphere and they have same speed but when I run the program, they go to end with different speeds. How they have same speed? If you help me, you will be my hero! Thank you.

Comment: That's because you `translate` several times (it's in a loop). The latter the sphere is in the loop, the more `translate` is applied to it, which is why if you create more "clouds" they will seem to be faster and faster.

Comment: @Iaancelot thank you so much you are a hero too. I was wrong about the translate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) do not just set a translation, it defines a translation matrix and multiplies the new translation matrix to the current matrix.

You have to construct the clouds at different positions:

```java
void setup() {
    // [...]

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Clouds C = new Clouds(20, i*40);
        clouds.add(C);
    }
}
```

```java
class Clouds {

    float xC, yC, zC, speedC;

    public Clouds(float x, float y) {
        xC = x;
        yC = y;
        zC = 0;

        // [...]
}
```

And to move `translate` in the [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) / [`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) block:

```java
class Clouds {
    // [...]

    public void drawClouds() {

        pushMatrix();
        translate(xC,yC);

        // [...]

        popMatrix();

        // [...]
    }

    public void makingClouds(float xF, float yF, float zF ) {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(xF, yF, zF);

        // [...]

        popMatrix();
    }
```

Example code:

```java
//main class
ArrayList<Clouds> clouds = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
    size(1200, 800, P3D);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Clouds C = new Clouds(20, i*40);
        clouds.add(C);
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < clouds.size(); i++) {
        clouds.get(i).drawClouds();
    }
}

//Clouds class

class Clouds {

    float xC, yC, zC, speedC;

    public Clouds(float x, float y) {
        xC = x;
        yC = y;
        zC = 0;
        speedC = 1;
    }

    public void drawClouds() {
        noStroke();
        pushMatrix();
        translate(xC,yC);
        makingClouds(100, 100, 100);
        popMatrix();

        if (xC > width - 780) {
            xC = -660; 
        }
        xC += speedC; 
    }

    public void makingClouds(float xF, float yF, float zF ) {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(xF, yF, zF);
        lights();
        scale(1, 1, 1);
        sphere(20);
        popMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awe Thank you so much @Rabbid76 you are a hero! I understood totally what were you saying about translate function and also variables.